# How to fill a list by another list that first list included 2th list in linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, list

I have 2 list of model.

**Product**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Stock**

```
public  class Stock
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of product that filled and a list of stock.

```
List <Product> productList = _productService.GetProduct().ToList();

List<Stock> stockList = new List<Stock>();
```

Now, I want fill stockList from productList using Linq.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Is `stockList` supposed to be a `List<StockViewModel>`?

Comment: @JimMischel ,ok I edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Select` you can create a new StockViewModel for every `Product` in `productList` and then you can just call `AddRange` to add them

```
stockList.AddRange(productList.Select(x => new Stock { Product = x }));
```

Comment: I'm guessing it was due to the confusing presentation of classes in the question but stockList is a List<Stock> not a List<StockViewModel>. Either the question has a typo, or he didnt provide the correct information for you to answer it effectively. Regardless, this will at least steer him in the right direction.

Comment: Good spot, I'll leave this here until the question gets updated and make sure I either update it or delete it once there is enough info :)

Comment: @TomDoesCode  if i have this :  public virtual Clientadmins ClientsAdmins{get;set;} in stock and i want fill it similiar product ,What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the StockViewModel like below.

```
stockList = productList.Select(x => new StockViewModel { Product = x }).ToList()
```

Comment: ok worked for me,now I  have another question that related to this answer. if i have  public virtual Clientadmins ClientsAdmins{get;set;} in stock and i want fill it similiar product ,What should I do ?

Comment: In this example The StockViewModel List is created based on the product List count, If you have separate list for ClientsAdmins ClientAdminsList and If you want to create a list based on the ClientAdmins for every productlist. you can create a list like this...       ClientAdminsList.Select(C => stockList.AddRange(productList.Select(x => new StockViewModel { Product = x, ClientsAdmins = C})))